# Creating a project in django

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pycharm, windows-10

I am a beginner in python. I am using python crash course book. I am learning to create a project in django using the terminal in pycharm.

These are the commands printed in the book as an example:

```
(1) (ll_env)learning_log$ django-admin.py startproject learning_log .
(2) (ll_env)learning_log$ ls learning_log ll_env manage.py
(3) (ll_env)learning_log$ ls learning_log __init__.py settings.py wsgi.py
```

(1) tells Django to set up a new project called learning_log

(2)shows that Django has created a new directory called learning_log and also created a file called manage.py

I am aware that "ls" is for linux and I tried using "dir" but it still doesnt work.

manage.py is not being created and i get the message "file not found"

anyone know how to deal with this? the entire learning django in the book from that uses linux so I really need to learn how to do it on windows.

Answer (score 0):

The manage.py file is in your learning_log directory, if step 1 didn't produce any error. On Windows terminal, 'dir' lists the folders and files in the current directory. 'cd' is to change directory.

You might want to use these two commands to check the files existence.

Comment: it didnt create manage.py though. also the .py files from the 3rd part

Comment: If manage.py file does not exist, it means the Django project didn't set up successfully. Is there any error in performing the first step?

Comment: i deleted the project folder and started all over again. i may have written a typo error now it shows the manage.py thank you so much!